# Read all columns in as string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read the entire dataframe as string.

The # of columns changes sometimes in the dataframe I pass, so I don't want to hardcode which columns specifically to read in.

The problems I'm dealing with are (a) lots of NaNs considered as floats when I want to consider as strings in many columns, (b) a person's last name, `NA`, getting read in as literally `not a value`:

```
     Unnamed: 0_level_0 Unnamed: 1_level_0
     Unnamed: 0_level_1 Unnamed: 1_level_1
              Last Name         First Name
4940                Lee              Harry
4941               Chin            Vincent
4942                NaN             Doreen
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are talking about reading `*.csv`, then consider using `dtype=str` as one of the parameters for `pd.read_csv`. [Check documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

If you already have a dataframe, you should use `df.to_string` method. Here is [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the parameters `dtype=str` `keep_default_na=False` and `na_values=''` to only accept empty strings as NaNs and not the legitimate string "Na".